# How do I make TouchableOpacity only clickable within its shape on mobile?

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

On web, shaping a TouchableOpacity makes it so only the shape is clickable, however on mobile the entire "box" surrounding the shape is clickable. Is there any way at all to make it so just the shape is clickable?

I have tried shaping the view and setting the style on both View and TouchableOpacity to overflow: 'hidden' but this also fails to contain the area which is touchable.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }

  onPress = () => {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text> Touch Here </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={[styles.countContainer]}>
          <Text style={[styles.countText]}>
            {this.state.count !== 0 ? this.state.count : null}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 640,
    height: 320,
    width: 320,
    overflow: 'hidden',
  },
  countContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 10,
  },
  countText: {
    color: '#FF00FF',
  },
});
```

Here's a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@baffledpanda/touchableproblem) example of my problem